# Examples of hyperbolic groups with non-hyperbolic subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

In a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425966/examples-of-locally-hyperbolic-groups), I asked about hyperbolic groups in which every finitely generated subgroup is hyperbolic. I am now curious about the reverse question: what are some examples of hyperbolic groups containing finitely generated non-hyperbolic groups?

Any non-coherent hyperbolic group will give an example (e.g. via the Rips construction). Do there exist examples of coherent hyperbolic groups containing f.g. non-hyperbolic subgroups?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure about examples where the hyperbolic group is coherent, but just for some more examples of hyperbolic groups with finitely generated non-hyperbolic subgroups, Brady found the first examples where the subgroup is even finitely presented (https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610799007644) and Italiano-Martelli-Migliorini found an example where the subgroup is even of type F (https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.14795).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an open problem to find a coherent hyperbolic group with a finitely generated, non-hyperbolic subgroup. See [Wise's survey article](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9780691185897-014/html?lang=en) for the state of the art on coherent groups.

Wise, Daniel T. (3-MGL)
**An invitation to coherent groups.**
*What's next?—the mathematical legacy of William P. Thurston*, 326–414,
Ann. of Math. Stud., 205, *Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, NJ, 2020*.

I suspect this is listed as a question there, but if not, it's very much in that spirit.

The theorem of Gersten that I mentioned [in answer to your last question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425992/1463) showed that there is no 2-dimensional example. All known coherent 3-dimensional groups are essentially 3-manifold groups. [Sam Nead's answer to that question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425967/1463) explained why finitely generated subgroups of hyperbolic 3-manifold groups are also hyperbolic.

As Matt Zaremsky mentions in comments, the key examples of finitely presented non-hyperbolic subgroups of hyperbolic groups are given by [the original example of Noel Brady](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610799007644) and the recent work of [Italiano--Martelli--Migliorini](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.14795). There are also related constructions by [Fujiwara](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08549), [Groves--Manning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11290), [Kropholler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09505), [Llosa Isenrich--Martelli--Py](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06531) and  [Lodha](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6716).

It would be very surprising if any of these examples were to turn out to be coherent. In fact, it is reasonable to conjecture that these examples are all incoherent, but I believe it is unknown in each case. Proving that Brady's example (say) is incoherent wouldn't answer your question, but would be a nice thing to do.

Comment: In the first sentence you probably want "finitely generated" before "non-hyperbolic"

Comment: @MattZaremsky: I certainly do! Fixed.

Comment: Brady's example is noncoherent.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : Great! Is this written down somewhere?

Comment: I do not think so, but it's not hard to see...

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I certainly believe it, but something needs to be said. Are you envisaging using combinatorial Morse theory on some other map to Z?

Comment: @HJRW: I wrote a sketch of the proof as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit too long for a comment: Brady's example is not coherent. Below is a sketch of the proof. The example constructed by Brady (see the reference in HJRW's answer) is obtained as a certain ramified covering over the space $X=\Theta^3$, where $\Theta$ is the theta-graph (two vertices and three edges). This graph is the union of two circles $C_1, C_2$. In particular, the space $X$ contains two 3-dimensional tori $C_1^3, C_2^3$, whose intersection contains a 2-dimensional torus $T$. Taking a ramified covering $Y\to X$, we obtain lifts $M_1, M_2$ of the tori $C_1^3, C_2^3$ to $Y$, such that $M_1, M_2$ are 3-dimensional compact hyperbolic manifolds intersecting in a subset containing a compact hyperbolic surface $S$ which is incompressible in both $M_1, M_2$ (the surface $S$ is a lift of the torus $T$). Furthermore, the manifolds $M_1, M_2$ are $\pi_1$-injective in $Y$. In particular, $\pi_1(Y)$ contains the amalgam $\pi_1(M_1)\star_H \pi_1(M_2)$, where $H$ is a certain quasiconvex subgroup of infinite index in both $\pi_1(M_1), \pi_1(M_2)$. Now, one uses the fact that both manifolds $M_1, M_2$ fiber over the circle, let $G_1, G_2$ denote surface fiber subgroups in $\pi_1(M_1), \pi_1(M_2)$. The intersection $G_1\cap H=G_2\cap H=F$ is a free group of infinite rank. Thus, the subgroup
$$
G=\langle G_1, G_2\rangle= G_1\star_F G_2
$$
is finitely generated but not finitely presentable (this can be checked, for instance, by looking at the 2-nd cohomology group of $G$ using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence).

I omitted many details in this proof but they are not hard to check once one understands details of Brady's construction.

Comment: I think you can also do as @HJRW suggested and build a different map from Brady's group to $\mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel is f.g. but not f.p. Brady builds his Morse function starting with a map from $\Theta^3$ to $S^1$ that wraps the edges around so as to ensure every ascending and descending link is a 2-sphere. If you instead "kill" one of the pairs of ascending directions and one of the pairs of descending directions, making them "flat", I believe now every ascending and descending link (of either a vertex or a flat edge) is a circle. (And then the kernel thing follows.)

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}$